# Watching variables contents in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

How can I watch the contents of several variables (for example, TreeSet's) simultaneously? I can watch contents of one TreeSet, clicking on it in "Variables" window, but I have no idea how to do that for several variables.

Comment: contents of several variables means value of that variables?

Comment: yes, I think it's what the toString method returns (not very familiar with Java)

Comment: An object's `toString()` method simply returns a `String` representation of that object, often used for debugging.

Comment: This video does an excellent job of showing you how to set breakpoints and watch variables in the Eclipse Debugger.
https://youtu.be/9gAjIQc4bPU

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use Expressions windows: while debugging, menu window -> Show View -> Expressions, then it has place to type variables of which you need to see contents

Comment: In my case with Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0) the Expressions window is under Other -> Debug.

Answer (score 23):

You can add a [watchpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_add_watch.htm) for each variable you're interested in.

> A watchpoint is a special breakpoint that stops the execution of an application whenever the value of a given expression changes, without specifying where it might occur. Unlike breakpoints (which are line-specific), watchpoints are associated with files. They take effect whenever a specified condition is true, regardless of when or where it occurred. You can set a watchpoint on a global variable by highlighting the variable in the editor, or by selecting it in the Outline view.

Comment: It seems that watchpoints are only available for "global" variables and not for private fields. This is however not really an issue when you have getter and setter methods, but still...

Comment: You're linking to a C/C++ Developement User Guide for Eclipse. I don't think it applies to Java as I tried this method and couldn't enable a watchpoint.

Comment: @katzenhut could you explain how to add it?

Comment: @Line :https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_watch.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by these ways.

Add `watchpoint` and while debugging you can see variable in **debugger window perspective** under variable tab.
OR
Add `System.out.println("variable = " + variable);` and see in console.

Comment: Sometimes I need to watch five - ten variables simultaneously, so debugging them with the console window is very hard.

Comment: Agreed with the OP. `println` is a very primitive way to debug.

Comment: @karlicoss so use debugger window perspective to watch variables.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me :(
I can watch the contents of only one TreeSet object [a](http://habreffect.ru/6bc/05cd22e52), or another [b](http://habreffect.ru/00c/2ac03e07a). And I want to watch them like [this](http://habreffect.ru/f53/93bed3f23)

Comment: @karlicoss links are broken (not that I'm surprised after that time), but I wonder what you meant... ;)

Answer (score 0):

And how about selecting the text you want to watch, and then using the shortcut "Ctrl + shift + I"