# How do I watch a variable in real-time when debugging on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, watch

I'm trying to watch a variable change in Eclipse's debug while my program run. But I can only find how to watch a variable when I have a breakpoint set, which pauses the program. I wanna watch the variable change in the eclipse window, while I'm using the program, without having the program pause each time the variable changes.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do this that I'm aware of.  The closest I could imagine is to have a thread that captures the thing you want to monitor and periodically prints its value.  You might have to synchronize access to that object at that point since multiple threads could be touching it.

Answer (score 1):

For varX
Add System.out.println("varX = " + varX); 
and see in console, or LogCat under tag = System.out

PS
You can see this answer in the link below, voted down! "Programmers" hate the simple solution, and for this reason the question remains unanswered.
[Watching variables contents in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664741/watching-variables-contents-in-eclipse-ide)