# java - such thing as an object alteration listener?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm developing in android. Is there such thing as some kind of object change/modifaction/alteration listener?

I have a JSONObject and would like to pinpoint exactly where the object is being changed. I am trying to create new JSONObjects from a piece of a another JSONObject. I think what is happening though is i'm just creating a reference to the JSONObject and accidentally updating the referenced object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for debugging purposes, you can add a watch on the variable in your IDE.

[Watching variables contents in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664741/watching-variables-contents-in-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create your own [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for object. In Java it can be achieved with extending [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) class or implementing [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) interface.